# WiFi on Dell Inspiron I7 5748

Tags: wireless, dell

I am new to Ubuntu and have installed it on my Dell Inspiron I7 5748 laptop.
The only problem I have is that once I completed the install, Ubuntu wont recognize my inbuilt WiFi card, nor will it recognize a Netgear USB WiFi card ( A6210) that I tried.
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Hewlas

rfkill list all:

```
-0: dell-rbtn: Wireless LAN 
Soft blocked :no 
Hard blocked: no 
2: hci0: Bluetooth 
soft blocked:no 
hard blocked : no
```

Comment: Please edit your question to add the result of the terminal command: `rfkill list all` Also, press the Airplane Mode key combination and run the command again. Then tell us if there is any change. Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: I ran the command and the output is as follows:-0: dell-rbtn: Wireless LAN    Soft blocked :no   Hard blocked: No    2: hci0: Bluetooth   soft blocked:no  hard blocked : no   Unsure what you mean by airplane mode key combination but I am searching for it.  Mnay thanks

Comment: Please edit your question to add the result of the terminal commands: `lsusb` and also: `uname -r` Thanks.

Comment: all of a sudden, the wifi is now working, so many thanks for your time and effort.

Comment: Connect to the internet using Wired connection and `apt update; apt upgrade` then follow these steps:
https://vovaprivalov.medium.com/fixing-problem-with-missing-wifi-adapter-on-ubuntu-18-04-dec50879a47e On the newest system you can use the *Software Sources > Additional Drivers* window.